# How can I create a different word for each player at the same time in vue js?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I have two players when I click the One Player button I want to disable the keyboard of player two, same with Two Player button. Each turn, they can only guess the word one of the time. It must different word for every player to avoid hint or cheating when the player turns. My problem is both players have the same word can guess. When I guess the letter, both letters appear in the blank square. Can somebody help me with my problem?

```
<div id="app">

        <!-- title bar / header -->
        <div id="header">
            <div id="header-title">
                Hangman
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- canvas where hangman is drawn -->
        <div id="board">
            <canvas id="board-canvas"></canvas>
        </div>

        <!-- row of blank letters for the selected word -->
        <div id="word">
            <div class="word-blankletter" v-for="letter in wordDivs" v-cloak>{{ letter }}</div>
        </div>

        <!-- keyboard -->
        <div id="keyboard">
            <div v-for="row in letters" class="keyboard-row">
                <letter-button v-for="letter in row" :letter="letter" :game-over="gameOver" :two-players="twoPlayers" :key="letter" @check="check(letter)" v-cloak></letter-button>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="word">
            <div class="word-blankletter" v-for="letter in wordDivs" v-cloak>{{ letter }}</div>
        </div>

        <div id="keyboard">
            <div v-for="row in letters" class="keyboard-row">
                <letter-button v-for="letter in row" :letter="letter" :game-over="gameOver" :two-players="twoPlayers" :key="letter" @check="check(letter)" v-cloak></letter-button>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- 'one player' 'play again' 'two players' -->
        <div id="buttons">
            <button class="buttons-button" :class="{ orange: !twoPlayers }" @click="onePlayer">One Player</button>
            <button id="playagain" class="buttons-button" :class="{ hidden: !gameOver }" @click="playAgain">Play Again</button>
            <button class="buttons-button" :class="{ orange: twoPlayers }" @click="twoPlayer">Two Players</button>
        </div>

    </div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script>


// random integer helper function
function randomInteger(min, max) {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
    }

// keyboard letter button component
Vue.component("letter-button", {
    props: ["letter", "gameOver", "twoPlayers"],
    template: "<button class='keyboard-row-letter' :id='letter' :disabled='disabled' @click='clicked()'>{{ letter }}</button>",
    data: function() {
        return {
            disabled: false
        };
    },
    // disable button on click, and send 'check' event to run check() in main vue instance
    methods: {
        clicked: function() {
            this.disabled = true;
            this.$emit("check");
        }
    },
    watch: {
        // disable all buttons on game over; re-enable all buttons on restart
        gameOver: function(newValue) {
            this.disabled = newValue;
        },
        // re-enable all buttons when a new two-player game is started
        twoPlayers: function(newValue) {
            this.disabled = false;
        }
    }
})

// main vue instance
var app = new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    data: {
        // keyboard letters
        letters: [
            ["Q", "W", "E", "R", "T", "Y", "U", "I", "O", "P"],
            ["A", "S", "D", "F", "G", "H", "J", "K", "L"],
            ["Z", "X", "C", "V", "B", "N", "M"]
        ],
        // words to choose from
        words: [
            "DOGS", 
            "CATS", 
            "MICE", 
            "HAWK"
        ],
        // currentWord will be set to a random word from above list
        currentWord: "",
        // each element in this array is a letter in the word
        wordDivs: [],
        // to count the number of wrong guesses
        guesses: 0,
        gameOver: false,
        lose: false,
        twoPlayers: false,
        // will be set to the canvas element in mounted()
        canvas: "",
        // will be set to the canvas 2d context
        ctx: ""
    },
    methods: {

        // draws the gallows
        drawGallows: function(ctx) {
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
            ctx.fillStyle = "#FF9800";
            ctx.strokeStyle = "#FF9800";
            ctx.beginPath();
            // left side
            ctx.moveTo(this.canvas.width / 10, this.canvas.height / 10);
            ctx.lineTo(this.canvas.width / 10, this.canvas.height * 0.95);
            // bottom side
            ctx.lineTo(this.canvas.width * 0.8, this.canvas.height * 0.95);
            // top side
            ctx.moveTo(this.canvas.width / 10, this.canvas.height / 10);
            ctx.lineTo(this.canvas.width * 0.4, this.canvas.height / 10);
            // hanging notch
            ctx.lineTo(this.canvas.width * 0.4, this.canvas.height / 5);
            ctx.stroke();
            ctx.closePath();
        },

        // fill this.wordDivs with empty strings to create the orange blanks
        makeBlanks: function() {
            for (var i = 0; i < this.currentWord.length; i++) {
                this.wordDivs.push("");
            }
        },

        // draws the appropriate part of the hanging man and/or 'game over'
        updateCanvas: function(ctx) {
            // this.drawGallows(ctx);
            // draw the head
            if (this.guesses === 0) {
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.arc(this.canvas.width * 0.4, (this.canvas.height / 5) + 20, 20, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
                ctx.stroke();
                ctx.closePath();
            } 
            // draw the torso
            else if (this.guesses === 1) {
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.moveTo(this.canvas.width * 0.4, (this.canvas.height / 5) + 40);
                ctx.lineTo(this.canvas.width * 0.4, this.canvas.height / 2);
                ctx.stroke();
                ctx.closePath();
            }
            // draw the right leg
            else if (this.guesses === 2) {
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.moveTo(this.canvas.width * 0.4, this.canvas.height / 2);
                ctx.lineTo((this.canvas.width * 0.4) + 30, this.canvas.height * 0.7);
                ctx.stroke();
                ctx.closePath();
            }
            // draw the left leg
            else if (this.guesses === 3) {
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.moveTo(this.canvas.width * 0.4, this.canvas.height / 2);
                ctx.lineTo((this.canvas.width * 0.4) - 30, this.canvas.height * 0.7);
                ctx.stroke();
                ctx.closePath();
            }
            // draw the right arm
            else if (this.guesses === 4) {
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.moveTo(this.canvas.width * 0.4, (this.canvas.height / 5) + 55);
                ctx.lineTo((this.canvas.width * 0.4) + 35, (this.canvas.height / 2) + 10);
                ctx.stroke();
                ctx.closePath();
            } 
            // draw the left arm and handle game over
            else if (this.guesses === 5) {
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.moveTo(this.canvas.width * 0.4, (this.canvas.height / 5) + 55);
                ctx.lineTo((this.canvas.width * 0.4) - 35, (this.canvas.height / 2) + 10);
                ctx.stroke();
                ctx.closePath();

                // game over
                ctx.font = "24px Roboto, sans-serif";
                ctx.fillText("Game Over", this.canvas.width * 0.4 - 30, this.canvas.height * 0.9);
                this.gameOver = true;
                this.lose = true;

                // fill in the word with the correct answer
                for (var i = 0; i < this.currentWord.length; i++) {
                    Vue.set(this.wordDivs, i, this.currentWord[i]);
                }
            }
            this.guesses++
        },

        // check the chosen letter when a letter component emits 'check'
        check: function(letter) {
            if (!this.gameOver) {
                var guessCorrect = false;
                // check if the letter is in the word, if so, fill it in
                for (var i = 0; i < this.currentWord.length; i++) {
                    if (letter == this.currentWord[i]) {
                        Vue.set(this.wordDivs, i, letter);
                        guessCorrect = true;
                    }
                }
                // if there are no more blanks in the word, you win
                if (!this.wordDivs.some(function(value) {return value == ""})) {
                    this.gameOver = true;
                    this.ctx.font = "24px Roboto, sans-serif";
                    this.ctx.fillText("You Win!", this.canvas.width * 0.4 - 30, this.canvas.height * 0.9);
                }
                // if they guess wrong, draw the man
                if (!guessCorrect) {
                    this.updateCanvas(this.ctx);
                }
            }
        },

        // re-initializes the game
        restart: function() {
            this.gameOver = false;
            this.lose = false;
            this.guesses = 0;
            this.wordDivs.splice(0);
            this.drawGallows(this.ctx);
            this.makeBlanks();
        },

        // resets the game to one-player mode and chooses a new word
        onePlayer: function() {
            if (this.twoPlayers) {
                this.twoPlayers = false;
                this.currentWord = this.words[randomInteger(0, this.words.length - 1)];
                this.restart();
            }
        },

        // starts two-player mode and prompts the user to enter a word
        twoPlayer: function() {
            if (this.twoPlayers) {
                this.twoPlayers = false;
                this.currentWord = this.words[randomInteger(0, this.words.length - 1)];
                this.restart();
            }
        },

        // chooses a new word and resets the game when 'play again' is clicked
        playAgain: function() {
            if (this.twoPlayers) {
                this.currentWord = this.words[randomInteger(0, this.words.length - 1)];
            }
            else {
                this.currentWord = this.words[randomInteger(0, this.words.length - 1)];
            }
            this.restart();
        }
    },

    // identify the canvas element and initialize it, draw the gallows, choose a word, and draw the blanks.
    mounted: function() {
        this.canvas = document.getElementById("board-canvas");
        this.canvas.width = document.getElementById("board").offsetWidth;
        this.canvas.height = document.getElementById("board").offsetHeight;
        this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
        this.ctx.lineWidth = 2;
        this.drawGallows(this.ctx);
        this.currentWord = this.words[randomInteger(0, this.words.length - 1)];
        this.makeBlanks();
    }
});
```

Comment: Too much code and too little explanation about what you are trying to solve. You need to clarify what you are trying to do and provide an example which just shows the exact problem. Only then, we might be able to help.

Comment: what @ssc-hrep3 said. something this 'detailed' needs pseudo code along with an explanation. otherwise there is too much to recreate and not enough of an understanding. Use CodeSandbox/CodePen/JSFiddle....

Comment: `When I guess the letter, both letters appear in the blank square.` Not sure if this is a typo in your question, but you have two sets of `div#word` and `div#keyboard` that are identical, which would explain why the letters are the same.